# plot.xts object --- how to make legend fonts bolder?

Tags: r, plot, xts

I have the following codes which works. I want to make the legend fonts bolder but I'm using the auto legend at the moment, just wondering if it is possible to do it? Many thanks in advance!

```
plot.xts(Margins, 
         screens = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
         col = brewer.pal(n=9,"PuBu")[c(8,4,6,9)], lwd = 6,
         legend.loc = c("topright"), auto.legend = T,
         main="Margin Comparison")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `font=2` as argument.

```
plot.xts(Margins, 
         screens = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
         col = brewer.pal(n=9,"PuBu")[c(8,4,6,9)], lwd = 6,
         legend.loc = c("topright"), auto.legend = T,
         main="Margin Comparison",
         font = 2
)
```

Comment: hi geektrader, thanks so much! I've got another question, is it possible to made the font bigger for legend and main please? thanks again!